# UIButton does not show up in custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I am banging my head on this but cannot figure out the issue.

I have a custom UIView: `FKPoiMiniDetail` and this is the implementation (FKPoiMiniDetail.m)

```
const static CGFloat kDialogLateralMargin   = 15.0;
const static CGFloat kDialogHeight          = 100.0;
const static CGFloat kDialogBottomMargin    = 10.0;
const static CGFloat kBottomButtonHeight    = 50.0;

@interface FKPoiMiniDetail ()
@property (nonatomic) float tabBarHeight;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger numberOfButtons;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *buttonBlocks;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PoI* myPoi;

@end
@implementation FKPoiMiniDetail

- (id) initWithTabBarHeight:(float)aTabBarHeight numberOfButtons:(NSUInteger)numButtons andPoi:(PoI*)aPoi{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.tabBarHeight = aTabBarHeight;
        self.numberOfButtons = numButtons;
        self.myPoi = aPoi;
        self.buttonBlocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and here I add the the buttons programmatically:

```
- (void) assignButton:(NSUInteger)index anImage:(UIImage*)image aText:(NSString*)text andCallback:(void(^)())cb{
    if (index > self.numberOfButtons) {
        ALog("ERROR: Index is greater than number of buttons");
        return;
    }
    [self.buttonBlocks addObject:cb];

    int imWidth = 20;
    int imHeight = 20;
    int imLabelSpacing = 8;
    CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];
    CGFloat overallWidth = labelSize.width + imWidth + imLabelSpacing;

    CGFloat test = self.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat buttonWidth = test / ((CGFloat) self.numberOfButtons);

    int x = index * buttonWidth;

    int y = self.frame.size.height - kBottomButtonHeight;

    UIButton *buttonContainer = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,buttonWidth,kBottomButtonHeight)];
    [buttonContainer addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    buttonContainer.tag = index;


    int firstImOrigin = x + (buttonWidth - overallWidth) / 2;
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(firstImOrigin, (kBottomButtonHeight - imHeight)/2, imWidth, imHeight)];
    [iv setImage:image];
    [buttonContainer addSubview:iv];


    CGRect lR = CGRectMake(firstImOrigin + imWidth + imLabelSpacing, (kBottomButtonHeight - labelSize.height)/2, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lR];
    label.text = text;

    [buttonContainer addSubview:label];
    [self addSubview:buttonContainer];
}
```

and this is the selector as the target of the UIButton:

```
- (void)buttonTouched:(UIButton*)b{
    void (^ myblock)() = [self.buttonBlocks objectAtIndex:b.tag];
    myblock();
}
```

Somewhere else I create this object and assign buttons like this:

```
FKPoiMiniDetail *md = [[FKPoiMiniDetail alloc] initWithTabBarHeight:self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height
                                                            numberOfButtons:2
                                                                     andPoi:annotation.aPoI];
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"detail.png"];
[md assignButton:0 anImage:im aText:@"Dettagli" andCallback:^{
     ALog("Button 0 pressed");
}];

[md assignButton:1 anImage:im aText:@"Naviga" andCallback:^{
     ALog("Button 1 pressed");
}];
[self.mapView addSubview:md];
```

The second button is empty, but the strange thing is this: clicking inside the button the callback does execute...

[image]

Debugging seems useless:
The variables for the first button:

[image]

and the variables for the second button:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: updated debug screenshots

Comment: You're using `x` to set frame of subview inside buttonContainer, whereas it seems to be real used (as defined) with the whole width of your `FKPoiMiniDetail`.  In other words, if I understood correctly, buttonContainer should have as origin.x 145 for the second button, but what's inside it should have the same as the ones for the first button (firtImOrigin = 29), etc.

Comment: Yep, maybe I am fused

Comment: Thank You!!! I spent 20 min of writing the question and 2 hours while figuring this. Should quit working for today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Decomposing" your `FKPoiMiniDetail`

`FKPoiMiniDetail`

> View
>    buttonContainer1 - buttonContainer2 — buttonContainer3, etc

So what's inside a `buttonContainer` should always have the same "frames" whereas it's `buttonContainer` `frame` that changes, according to the number of buttons, since `buttonContainer` will be their superview.

So you declare:

```
int x = index * buttonWidth;
int y = self.frame.size.height - kBottomButtonHeight;
```

The'll help setting the `buttonContainer` `frame`.

But `label` and `iv` should not depend of them, only depend of the height and the width of `[buttonContainer frame]` since they seems to be centered.

I guess that from you code, if you do at the end `[self addSubview:iv]` and `[self addSubview:label];` you may see them.

Comment: Concise answer, that was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with setting images on `UIImageView` in the past and my solution has been changing the order to this:

`[buttonContainer addSubview:iv];
[iv setImage:image];`

First adding he subview and then setting the image.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue was that there is a bug in the frame bounds, see comment of Larme in my question.